Pop to previous page on .NET MAUI Android seems to reload the whole UI, which causes poor navigation performance
I am using Navigation Page on .NET Maui project, and whenever I pop to the previous page on the stack (with or without animation) it shows a blank white page for a moment before it displays the page content. The transition is especially long if the previous page has large complex UI.
It is as if the pages were completely reloaded when reappearing.
It works fine on iOS, and the problem was not present in Xamarin.Forms..
Anyone knows the cause or any workaround ?

Did your project target .net 8.0? In addition, could you please show the code about navigation?

My project targets .net 8.0
Here is my navigation code :
await MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(async () =>
{
await (Application.Current.MainPage as NavigationPage).PushAsync(page);
});
And the Pop part:
return MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() => (Application.Current.MainPage as NavigationPage).PopAsync()); 
Same behavior when I use the physical back button

Did you try to use the Navigation.PushAsync() and Navigation.PopAsync() instead? Or you can try to use Shell instad of NavigationPage.
